# How to get all the fields from Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I'm working on Sitecore 6.6. I wan to get all the fields for a particular item.

I'm getting all the fields using this

```csharp
FieldCollection fieldcollection = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Id, LanguageManager.GetLanguages(Sitecore.Context.Database).Where(i => i.CultureInfo.ToString() == Globallanguage).FirstOrDefault(), Sitecore.Data.Version.Latest).Fields;
```

And looping through each field and adding items to a list

```csharp
    foreach (Field field in fieldcollection)
    {
        if(fields!=null)
        {
        .....
        }
    }
```

But after returning some fields it is throwing me an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Code.Pipeline.NotFoundRedirector.GetAllMappedUrls()

I wanted to know whether I'm using correct method to get all fields

Comment: Can you add the error you're getting?

Comment: Check log files for more details. Can you post the whole exception from there?

Comment: And what is it that you're doing in the foreach loop? I assume it's not just an empty loop? Also, is it always on the same field you get this? Is there any exception in the logfiles?

Comment: I'm adding the rquired fields to a list, and binding them to a gridview @Trayek

Comment: Check for null values.

Comment: "returning some fields it is throwing me an error" - can you check which field is returning null? It may be a system field, you might just be able to check `if (field != null)` to skip over those, depends on your usage.

Comment: I have checked for null values and checked even if fields contains null or not

Comment: Do check my updated question @Trayek

Comment: Are you able to set breakpoints and debug the code? Is it hitting those breakpoints? Step through the code and see where the error is thrown. The error message shown does not make sense, not without a lot more knowledge and context of your code.

Comment: The code cannot be debugged,I think the error is more like getting all fields.Am I calling the method correctly for getting all fields @ jammykam

Comment: If you have the source code, then the code **can** be debugged, you might be looking in at the wrong place though. It _seems_ like you have a custom pipeline in place and the error is occuring there much earlier. Disable it or fix that error first.

Comment: I think the problem lies in the method.Am I using the right method to get all fields. @ jammykam

Comment: ERROR Corsair 301 : Exception Occureed Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Corsair.Web.UI.Code.Pipeline.NotFoundRedirector.GetAllMappedUrls() 
3748 07:52:32 WARN LinkBuilder. Site 'Corsair-Web' should have defined 'targethostname' property in order to take participation in site resolving process. 
3864 07:52:35 INFO Inside NotFoundRedirector : FilePath : /test.txt  @Marek Musielak

Comment: Can you post the **whole** code of GetAllMappedUrls method?

Answer (score 0):

I have got all the fields by changing the version and adding getall() method

```
 FieldCollection fieldcollection = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(TargetId, LanguageManager.GetLanguages(Sitecore.Context.Database).Where(i => i.CultureInfo.ToString() == Globallanguage).FirstOrDefault(), Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(TargetId).Version).Fields;        
 fieldcollection.ReadAll();
```

The loop goes as usual

```
   foreach (Field field in fieldcollection)
    {
        if(fields!=null)
        {
        .....
        }
    }
```